# How do i round up values in XPath

Tags: xpath, bpel

Does anyone know how do i round up a value in business rules (BPEL)? i tried fn:ceiling(num) and @round(num) and even Bigdecimal Round_Up  nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot round any numbers in BPEL, but you can do that with XPath 1.0, which is the default expression language in BPEL. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-round